# How do I see the normal Xcode interface instead of seeing the debug screen

Tags: xcode, debugging, interface, mode

Sometime when opening phonegap applications in xcode I get the following screen. How can I get back to the screen where I can edit and run my app in the emulator?
http://s2.postimg.org/prlr3br4p/Screen_Shot_2014_05_22_at_21_09_56.png

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the menu bar? View => Debug Area => Hide Debug Area
Or you can use the shortcut SHIFT-COMMAND-Y.